# Запятая в сравнительных оборотах

Tags: пунктуация

Можно так расставить запятые или совсем по-другому?

1. Тайга, огромная, как море, раскинулась на сотни километров.
2. Доцент, злой как собака, вчера опять всех белье стирать заставлял.
3. Я как дурак простоял весь день в очереди и все без толку.
4. Юра Деточкин, как Робин Гуд, все деньги от продаж краденых машин отдавал несчастным сиротам.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Тайга, огромная, как море, раскинулась на сотни километров.

Я бы запятую перед "как" не поставил:

***Тайга, огромная как море, раскинулась…***

======

Из словаря Лебедевой Л.А. "Устойчивые сравнения русского языка" (М., 2015):

> ***КАК МОРЕ.*** О земном или водном пространстве, кажущемся безграничным.
>
> *Поезд выскочил из горного ущелья в долину и остановился на берегу **широкого как море** озера.* С. Скиталец. Дом Черновых.
>
> *Степь лежала кругом тёмная, плоская, **бескрайняя как море**.* А. Коптяева. Дружба.

=====================

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (НАДО ЛИ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ "КАК МОРЕ")**

Получил несколько дней назад от кого-то оценку "-1" за этот свой ответ. Очень этому удивился…

Обратился с вопросом в справочное бюро Грамоты.ру (см. http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_477539 ). Может, кому-то мнение этой службы будет интересно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слава, устойчивые сравнения тоже могут обособляться.

Comment: _"...устойчивые сравнения тоже могут обособляться"._ ===  А я разве с этим спорю? Я лишь сказал, что в **приведённом в вопросе предложении** запятую бы перед "как" не поставил бы (ну не могу я это предложение прочитать **с паузой перед "как"!**), и попытался аргументировать допустимость такого решения.

Comment: Тайга, огромная, как море, раскинулась.. Трактовка  справочной службы по поводу отнесенности оборота к глаголу - это что-то из области фантазий на грамматическую тему. (Вообще, у нас часто пытаются обнаружить двусмысленность, которую трудно найти даже при очень большом желании это сделать). Интересно, существуют ли предложения, в которых обособленное и отнесенное к глаголу сравнение находится в препозиции  по отношению к глаголу?

Comment: _"Вообще, у нас часто пытаются обнаружить двусмысленность, которую трудно найти даже при очень большом желании это сделать"._ ===  Бывает и такое... Бывает и другое: кто-то видит необходимость в запятых там, где вполне возможно и куда лучше обойтись без них.

Comment: Слава, я тоже обратился в Грамму.ру. Вот ответ.                               В приведенном Вами предложении запятая действительно не нужна, так как при ее постановке становится неясным, к чему относится сравнение "как море" ("огромная как море" или "раскинулась как море").

Comment: Кстати, такой пункт в правилах оговорен.

Answer (score 2):

Мои рассуждения таковы: 
1.Тайга, огромная, как море, раскинулась на сотни километров (определение, распространенное с помощью сравнительного оборота, стоит после определяемого слова).
2.Доцент, злой как собака, вчера опять всех белье стирать заставлял (аналогичный случай, но сравнительный оборот не отделен запятой, т.к. является устойчивым выражением).
3.Я как дурак простоял весь день в очереди и все без толку (сравнительный оборот не отделяется запятой, так как является устойчивым выражением)
4.Юра Деточкин, как Робин Гуд, все деньги от продаж краденых машин отдавал несчастным сиротам ("как" здесь в значении "подобно",значит, это сравнительный оборот)
Со всеми Вашими знаками я согласен

Answer (score 2):

3) Я как дурак простоял весь день в очереди, и все без толку.

Союз И имеет присоединительное значение.

Пример:

Свистел, покрикивая, прислушивался ― и все без толку (А. П. Гайдар).

В третий раз к тебе прихожу, и все без толку (Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (НАДО ЛИ ОБОСОБЛЯТЬ "КАК МОРЕ")**

1) Обособлять желательно, так как без обособления ударение падает только на сравнение, а определение остается в безударной позиции, что, как правило, не входит в задачу автора, например:

Там земля представляет собой равнину, плоскую, как море, и заросшую полынью.

Он одет в широкий, как море, черный плащ.

Вверху безучастно шумел ветер хвойными вершинами. Один среди леса, огромного, как море.

2) А вот вариант без обособления, но с инверсией. Здесь ударение на месте, то есть падает на определение:

«Красавица народная, как море полноводная"